# Using 'Day' Function in VB within IF Statement to change date and send form based on weekday

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net

I am writing a Windows application which navigates through the WebBrowser control and automates filling forms based on certain criteria. On a few specific forms, there are dates that are being pulled in order to retrieve certain information based on that criteria. The problem is that on Mondays, the start date would have to be for the previous week's Friday. With All other days (Tue-Friday), the start date is just the previous day. I am trying to use an If statement to solve this issue, but when I run the form, it does not fill the correct days.

Here is what I am using:

```
Public Class Form1
    Inherits Form

    Dim otherdays = Format(Now.AddDays(-1), "M/d/yyyy")
    Dim mondays = Format(Now.AddDays(-3), "M/d/yyyy")
    Dim current = Format(Now, "M/d/yyyy")

    Private Sub approval1()
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("txtDate").SetAttribute("Value", mondays)
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Search").InvokeMember("click")
    End Sub

    Private Sub approval2()
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("txtDate").SetAttribute("Value", otherdays)
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Search").InvokeMember("click")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "IM Approval" Then
            WebBrowser1.Navigate("https:")
            WaitForPageLoad()

            'This is the part that does not work:
            If Now.Day = Day.Monday Then
                approval1()
                WaitForPageLoad()
                WebBrowser1.Navigate("javascript: ('','')")
            Else
                approval2()
                WaitForPageLoad()
                WebBrowser1.Navigate("javascript: ('','')")
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

The WebBrowser navigating through the Javascript is not the issue. Filling the date is the only issue.

Comment: When you step through the code, is it getting into the top condition block?`If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "IM Approval" Then`?  Is it putting anything in the form elements?

Comment: @georgecb It sounds like the current date is dated the previous date, skipping weekends.  In VBA datetime is calculated using the time set in the computer's regional setting.  You can check yours and see if there's any clue.

Comment: `Now.Day` return the day of the month (an integer). Replace it in your If statement with `Now.DayOfWeek`.

Comment: Also replace `Day.Monday` with `DayOfWeek.Monday`

Answer (score 1):

The reason your check for the day of the week isn't working is that you are checking the day of the month instead. Here is a simpler version of for class with the if statement corrected.

```
Public Class Form1
    Inherits Form

    Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "IM Approval" Then
            WebBrowser1.Navigate("https:")
            WaitForPageLoad()

            Dim adjust As Integer = If(Now.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday, -3, -1)
            WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("txtDate").SetAttribute("Value", Format(Now.AddDays(adjust), "M/d/yyyy"))
            WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Search").InvokeMember("click")

            WaitForPageLoad()
            WebBrowser1.Navigate("javascript: ('','')")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```